# DataTable header template columns (custom control, dropdown) are not getting reset

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm having templates in the header of primeNg DataTable.

1. Custom DateRange Filter (child) component
2. Dropdown to list activities
3. Regular column
4. Regular template column

I've a Global Filter Reset button, on which all filters has to be reset. `dataTable.reset()` method is resetting regular column (#3) and regular template custom (#4), but NOT other header controls (#1, #2).

I tried to invoke `childComponent.Reset()` using `@ViewChild` option, but I'm getting the `childComponent` as `"undefined"` on runtime. I could see `@ViewChild` option is working for regular child controls outside the dataTable.

How can I reset all controls in the primeNg DataTable in the right way?

```
    <p-column field="updatedOn" header="Updated On" sortable="custom" (sortFunction)="dateSort($event)" [style]="{'width':'180px'}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
            <date-range-filter #dateRangeFilter (dateRangeUpdated)="onRangeUpdated($event)"></date-range-filter>
        </template>
        <template let-col let-val="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <div class="bodyText">
                {{val[col.field] | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'}}
            </div>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="activity" header="Activity" sortable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="equals" [style]="{'width':'100px', 'overflow':'visible'}">
        <template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
            <p-dropdown #activityType appendTo="body" [options]="_activityList" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" (onChange)="memoTable.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"
                styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
        </template>
        <template let-col let-val="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <span class="ActivityBox" [ngClass]="getActivityColor(val[col.field])">{{getActivityType(val[col.field])}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="User" header="User" sortable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [style]="{'width':'95px'}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="comment" header="comment" sortable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <template let-col let-val="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <div>
                <div class="NotesColumn" [ngClass]="val[col.field].length > 15? 'underlined' : ''" (mouseenter)="op.show($event)" (mouseleave)="op.hide($event)">
                    {{val[col.field]}}
                </div>
                <p-overlayPanel #op [styleClass]="overlayDiv" [appendTo]="overlayTarget">
                    <div class="overlayDiv">
                        {{val[col.field]}}
                    </div>
                </p-overlayPanel>
            </div>
        </template>
    </p-column>
```

Comment: Resetting p-dropdown can be accomplished by - 1: include `[(ngModel)]="_selectedActivityType"` to capture the selected value. 2: Reset `_selectedActivityType` to default value from the activityList - 'this._selectedActivityType = this._activityList[0]'. The issue still persists on custom control. I believe the component is not getting rendered during the globalFilterClear event which results in error `Cannot read property 'clearDates' of undefined`. `clearDates()` is custom component public method.

Answer (score 0):

I 've found a fix for this issue on clearing controls on the custom component.

```
1. Use ElemenRef to get hold of the elements on the page. 
    constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {}

    // Clear all filters from DataTable
    clearAllFilters(dataTable: DataTable) {
      dataTable.reset()
      dataTable.globalFilter.value = ''
      DateRangeComponent.clearDateFilter(this._element)
    }

2. Use querySelector to get the control.    
    public static clearDateFilter(pageElement: ElementRef) {
        let dri = pageElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#dateRangeInput')
        dri.value = ""
        dri.tooltipText = ""

        // Dispatch a 'change' event to trigger onSearchKeyUp method to clear filter based on date range.
        var event = new Event('change')
        dri.dispatchEvent(event)

        // Another way of doing this is dri.focus() followed by dri.blur() to fire change event.
    }

    // Html dateRangeInput Control
    <input #dateRangeInput class="theInput" id="dateRangeInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" pTooltip="{{_dateRangeInputText}}"
         tooltipPosition="top" (keyup)="onSearchKeyUp($event)" (change)="onSearchKeyUp($event)" (keydown)="onSearchKeyDown($event)">

    // The below code is just test logic to ensure the control is reset 
    // and an event is emitted back to the parent component.
    private onSearchKeyUp(event: any) {
        let input = event.target.value

        if (input.length === 0) {
            this.reset()
            this.dateRangeUpdated.emit(this)
        }
    }
```